# Python: search in a list give TypeError

Tags: python, list, search

Can you guys help me with these code below. I got the TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable when put everything together. I've tried to run smaller pieces of code separately and I worked well though:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    result = []
    for i in range (len(doc_list)-1):
        if keyword.lower() in doc_list[i].lower().rstrip(".,").split():
            result.append[i]
    return result
```

> **Error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable**

Separate pieces of code run well:

```
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
new_list = doc_list[0].lower().rstrip(".,").split()
print(new_list)
```

Comment: @DanielHao where did you get that from?

Comment: My bad - poor memory. Mess up with other terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code as shown below
Please tweak it to your satisfaction

```
      def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
            result = [ ]
            for i in range(len(doc_list) - 1):
                if keyword.lower() in doc[i].lower().rstrip('.,').split():
                      result.append(doc[i])
            print(result)
```

Should we create the list and test it, here's what you will get

Input:

```
      doc_list = ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino.', 'They bought a car', 'Casinoville']

      word_search(doc_list, 'Casino')
```

Output:

```
       ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino']
```

Comment: Big thanks! But when I tried "car" and it didn't work. How come?

Comment: Just a second let me look into that

Comment: Mine works just fine...... it returned ['they bought a car']

Comment: I mean when you try a list with this element ['They bought a car, and a horse]

Comment: Show me the code, the exact same way you typed it. If there was an error, also let me know the error message

Comment: By the way if you are satisfied with the code I provided, you can vote it up using the up arrow and also verify it as an answer.....

Comment: def word_search(doc_list, kw):
 result = []
 for i in range (len(doc_list)-1):
  if kw.lower() in doc_list[i].lower().rstrip(".,").split():
   result.append(doc_list[i])
 return result

test = word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino.', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'],'car')
print(test)

Comment: Oh man sorry I dont know how to post code in comment section.

Comment: test = word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino.', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'car')

I test with this and it gives a list with nothing in it.

Comment: No problem.... Just delete the comma from the car just before the and

Comment: Yeah. But what If I still want to have that comma in the test list? How can we run the code?

Comment: I think I got it now:

`if kw.lower() in doc_list[i].lower().rstrip(".,").replace(",","").split():`

Comment: I guess the comma is depriving the car from being just car. So if you space the comma from the car, it will work.....  your method is more efficient by the way. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updated `result.append(i)` from `result.append[i]` as `append` is a method:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.
    
    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    result = []
    for i in range (len(doc_list)-1):
        print(i)
        if keyword.lower() in doc_list[i].lower().rstrip(".,").split():
            result.append(i)
    return result

doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
print(word_search(doc_list, 'casino'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append`is a built-in function for list.

```
 result.append[i]
```

You are trying to fetch i'th element from the "function". Hence it shows an error.

You actually want

```
result.append(i)
```

```
result = []
for i in range (len(doc_list)-1):
    if keyword.lower() in doc_list[i].lower().rstrip(".,").split():
        result.append(i)
return result
```